# What is the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1+t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

In a table and also on WolframAlpha, I stumbled upon this

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+1%2F%281%2Bt%29

So the Laplace transform of $1/(1+t)$ is apparently $-e^s \text{Ei}(-s)$. There was no explanation of this $\text{Ei}(-s)$ function in neither the table nor WolframAlpha. So what is this weird function?

Comment: It is the [exponential integral](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: From that result, you can deduce the standard definition of this special function: $$\text{Ei}(s)=-e^{s}\mathcal{L}\left[(1+t)^{-1}\right](-s)=-\int_0^\infty e^{s(1+t)}(1+t)^{-1}\,dt=-\int_{-s}^{\infty} e^{-u}u^{-1}\,du$$
where $u=-s(1+t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already been informed by @MhenniBenghorbal, it is an exponential integral. 
$$
\mathcal{L}\Big\{\frac{1}{1+t}\Big\} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{t + 1}dt
$$
We can get the Laplace transform by letting $u = 1 + t$. Then $du = dt$ and we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{t + 1}dt &= \int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-su + s}}{u}du\\
&= e^s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-su}}{u}du
\end{align}
where $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-su}}{u}du = -\text{Ei}(-s)$. Thus
$$
\mathcal{L}\Big\{\frac{1}{1+t}\Big\} = -e^s\text{Ei}(-s).
$$